# ratio zero over zero uncertainty

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was just wondering if the following statement is correct. Assume I have a ratio $\frac{x-y}{z}$ for some variables $x,y,z$ and I also know that when $z=0$ I have $x\equiv y$. Does that imply that the ratio is zero when $z=0$? Or this is an uncertainty $\frac{0}{0}$ and I can't say for sure what the ratio is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\dfrac{x - y}{z}$, if when $z = 0, x\equiv y$, then there exists no meaningful ratio.

So no, in this context, the ratio would not be zero: $\dfrac 00$ is indeterminate $\neq 0$

The ratio could only be zero if and only if $x = y$ for some non-zero $z$.

Comment: Both answers are good. That was the first though. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!